Creating a deep copy of intrusive list
I have an .hpp looking similar to this
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

struct Tag;
using Hook = list_base_hook< tag<Tag> >;

class Str : public Hook
{
public:
    Str(int n) : n_(n) {}
    Str(const Str& s) : n_(s.n_) {}

    int n_;
};

using List = list< Str, cache_last<true>, base_hook<Hook> >;
using Map = std::unordered_map<std::string, List>;

and I have 2 threads that are using Map, a writer and reader, but I can't lock the writer thread for long, thus I need to create a deep copy of Map for the reading thread to work on. My problem with that is that intrusive list is movable but not copy-able so I tried to create the list dynamically like so
int deep_copy_map(Map& orig, Map& copy)
{
    for (auto& it: orig) {
        List list_copy;
        for (auto& it1: it.second) {
            list_copy.push_back(*(new Str{it1}));
        }
        copy.insert({ it.first, std::move(list_copy) });
    }
}

but now I'm leaking Str objects as the intrusive list doesn't destroy its elements. So I next tried to add this to my .hpp
class List_ : public List
{
public:
    ~List_()
    {
        while (!this->empty())
        {
            Str* node = &this->front();
            this->pop_front();
            delete node;
        }
    }
};

using Map = std::unordered_map<std::string, List_>;

and update the copy to
int deep_copy_map(Map& orig, Map& copy)
{
    for (auto& it: orig) {
        List_ list_copy;
        for (auto& it1: it.second) {
            list_copy.push_back(*(new Str{it1}));
        }
        copy.insert({ it.first, std::move(list_copy) });
    }
}

but now I get the error
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, List_>::insert(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
    copy.insert({ it.first, std::move(list_copy) });

Is there a way to create a deep copy of Map without leaking memory?
I have limited access to the reader thread code, and I'm only allowed to make changes there if they are absolutely necessary

If you need to copy the list, why are you using an intrusive list at all? Just use std::list, or std::vector if the invalidation requirements are practical

@Caleth The decision to use intrusive list was done long before I've even seen this code for the first time, this is legacy code that no one wants to touch unless it is absolutely necessary, hence the last comment in the question

The intrusive list library doesn't provide standalone containers. The expectation is that you have the ownership in something like std::vector, and wrap it all in the interface you require.
using bi = boost::intrusive;

class List
{
    using Intrusive = bi::list< Str, bi::cache_last<true>, bi::base_hook<Hook> >;
    std::vector<Str> elems;
    Intrusive list;
public:
    Intrusive::iterator begin() { return list.begin(); }
    Intrusive::iterator end() { return list.end(); }

    Intrusive::iterator insert(Intrusive::iterator where, const Str & what) { return list.insert(where, elems.push_back(what)); }

    // other members to taste
};

using Map = std::unordered_map<std::string, List>;

With this, Map is now copyable, and you have strong-exception-safe ownership.
